# tkinter.TclError: can't find package ttk::theme:: for pyinstaller exe onefile

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

So I'm trying to turn my GUI tkinter application to an .exe file to share it with others. However, doing so, I faced error:

```
tkinter.TclError: can't find package 
ttk::theme::D:\DCPU Forecast and Occupancy Python Excel App\dist\forest-light\forest-light.tcl
```

or

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package ttk::theme::forest-light
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python Excel App Havi.py", line 72, in <module>
  File "tkinter\ttk.py", line 522, in theme_use
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package ttk::theme::forest-light
```

I have done everything for this thing, by changing the the code in the python script

```
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('forest-light')
```

And by loading the ttk theme with tk.call

```
root.tk.call('source', 'forest-light.tcl')
```

And also using the resourcepath of MEIPASS

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

 root.tk.call('source', resource_path('forest-light.tcl'))
```

or

```
root.tk.call('source', resource_path('D:\DCPU Forecast and Occupancy Python Excel App\dist\forest-light\forest-light.tcl'))
```

But it did not work when I try to convert it to one file, it does work when I use it with a console. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you include the files or folder for the theme into the executabe?

Comment: Wait, I think I will just explain it in detail. So, I have already included the theme in my project file. But when I try to turn it into executable, it shows that error. I knew that pyinstaller didn't directly recognize my folder file, so I move it into the distribution folder executable. However, I still face the same error.

Comment: It seems that you call `root.tk.call("source", ...)` after `style.theme_use(...)`.  You need to call `root.tk.call("source", ...)` before `style.theme_use(...)`.

Comment: I have already done that too and it doesn't work...

Comment: If you have already done that, then you should get another error instead of posted one. Post that error and better a [mre].

Comment: "style = ttk.Style(root)
root.tk.call('source', 'forest-light.tcl')
style.theme_use('forest-light.tcl')" this is my edited code.  this is the new error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python Excel App Havi.py", line 72, in <module>
  File "tkinter\ttk.py", line 522, in theme_use
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package ttk::theme::forest-light.tcl"

Comment: I think it's because pyinstaller tkinter ttktheme the file "ttk.py" doesn't recognize the theme "forest-light" maybe? Hence, the error. I tried to check the "ttk.py" file as a result, but I don't quite get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Typo: `style.theme_use("forest-light.tcl")` should be `style.theme_use("forest-light")` (without `.tcl`).

Comment: Can I ask a question again? If I were to use the filedialog and askopenfilename function to upload the excel file to the executable app, how can I make sure that it shows the data in the treeview? I knew that the problem was that pyinstaller was dependent on the data to be explicitly told in the distribution file, so I was wondering if there were any workaround for it.

Comment: It is better to raise another question.